# Running commentary of actions on other list than Issue Tracking List in SharePoint Online (BPOS)?

Tags: sharepoint

I had a look at http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=154 and I wonder if the running commentary on an item in that example is possible to have on other types lists?

It's SharePoint Online so we can't deploy custom code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have to do with the list type, it is the column. And you can do it manually in other lists, it does not require custom code.

Under Columns in the List Settings, click on a Multiple lines of text column. In the Change Column screen, set Append Changes to Existing Text to Yes and click OK.